# Nested GridView Visibility is not working properly

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a nested gridview. There seems to be a problem with the Visibility. In the code below, OuterCollection and InnerCollection have HideInUI property which I inverse to determine the visibility (ex. if true, hide).

However, on the 2nd HideInUI, if the 1st item is hidden, it seems to hide everything else.

```
    <GridView x:Name="GridView_Outer"
              InnerCollectionsSource="{Binding Path=OuterCollection}">
    <GridView.InnerCollectionTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding Path=HideInUI, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                <Button Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                        IsEnabled="False" 
                        Style="{StaticResource CategoryButton}"/>
                <GridView x:Name="GridView_Inner"
                      InnerCollectionsSource="{Binding Path=InnerCollection}">
                    <GridView.InnerCollectionTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Width="120"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=GridView_Outer, Path=DataContext.SelectPaymentTypeCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PaymentAmountTypeID}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=ScreenTitle}"
                            Visibility="{Binding Path=HideInUI, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            </Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
```

**Edit**

Sorry for the confusion. But what happens is.

Ex. Category 1 has Item 1, Item 2, Item 3. If HideInUI is true in Item1, Item2 and Item3 becomes hidden also. But if Item 2 or Item3 is HideInUI instead, it works properly. I can't seem to find out why.

Comment: So you're hiding the parent (The StackPanel) of the 2nd (The Button) which it's nested in, so it would be expected behavior that if you hide the parent, then the childs visibility would become collapsed also...

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have here is that you are setting the visibility of the StackPanel(in your outer gridview) that contains the rest of your solution. You have to look at it as boxes, everything within it is affected by its parents in some ways.

The tabulation is a great way to help you understand which block contains what, in your example, you can clearly see that your GridView contains one thing, which is a DataTemplate. This DataTemplate also contains one thing which is the StackPanel, and so on. In your case, your StackPanel contains everything else, so if you hide it, you hide everything in it also.

What I think you actually want, it is to hide the button in the "Outer GridView", in this case, you should set visibility of the "Title" button instead of setting the visibility of the whole StackPanel.

Cutting and pasting your code:

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=HideInUI, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

from your StackPanel to your "Title" button should do the trick.